# API Graph Facebook

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, graph

he comenzado una app para hacer sorteos con resultados "al azar". Se me ocurrió tb ofrecer que algún conocido use esta web para que le haga la selección de ganador de manera aleatoria entre los "likes" de una publicación de fbook o Instagram. Hasta ahí, la idea la tengo clara. He creado una app en la web de developers de Facebook y he trasteado la herramienta web de la API GRAPH. Todo parece sencillo, pero no logro obtener, en esa misma web ninguna información de alguien que no sea yo mismo. Por ejemplo, si hago un get de mis amigos (Get/v16.0/me?fields?=friends) solo me arroja un total, pero no el detalle de cada uno de ellos. En los likes, solo puedo ver las páginas que me gustan a mí, no los likes de otros usuarios en mis posts (ni de quienes son). Puedo ver mis posts, pero poco más, nada de info de quien interactúa con ellos. Aún no he implantado código en mi web, puesto que no siquiera he sido capaz de conseguir ver nada con la herramienta propia de meta.

Si alguien puede darme alguna nueva vía de pruebas, estaré muy agradecido. Lo que necesito, ahora mismo es, con la herramienta web de api Graph de Facebook, ver quién ha interactuado con mis posts (me gusta/compartir).

Un saludo y gracias a todos!.